# $(...).tabs is not a function jQuery UI 1.10.4

Tags: jquery-ui

Getting this error $(..).tabs not a function.

here are my imports

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" type="text/css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>`

Can you help debugging that.

JSP FILE

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"   prefix="fn" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">    
<title>Login to Web Service Details Tool</title>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" type="text/css"></link>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs1">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs2">Web Service Dashboard</a></li>         
        <li><a href="#tabs3">Console</a></li>

    </ul>

     <div id="tabs1">
        <jsp:include page="overview.jsp" />
    </div>
    <div id="tabs2">
        <jsp:include page="dashboard.jsp"/>         
    </div>

    <div id="tabs3">
        <jsp:include page="menu.jsp" />
    </div>

 </div>
 <br><br>
```

This was working until today, i don't know why it stopped working & console is throwing me error `tabs` is not defined function

Comment: Just a heads up, you're using jQuery 2.1.1, and jQueryUI 1.10.4.

Comment: Can you post the HTML, also check to make sure the reference is correct i.e. the files exist in a folder called **js** under the page you're creating

Comment: +1 to @christiandev, I expect that your jQueryUI file is not getting loaded properly.

Comment: I don't know the jquery file is from jqueryui.com & also files are there in js folder

Comment: @garima, check in your browser if the javascript file is being loaded properly.

Comment: You have references to two different files in the two code snippets, one is to `jquery-ui-1.10.4.js`, the other to `jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js`

Answer (score 2):

The structure would need to look like this:

```
page.html
-js (folder)
--jquery-2.1.1.js
--jquery-ui-1.10.4.js
```

The html file would then have the references as you've show above:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css" type="text/css"></link>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/home.js"></script>
```

You could also use chrome dev tools (F12) to check if the resources have loaded

**NOTE**: if you're `home.js` is using any *jquery* functionality, this file should always be added after the jquery files.

**EDIT**: based on comment

make sure you're using it like `$("#name").tabs();` and not `$("#name").tabs;`

Comment: resources are loaded, I can see them in console. but console throwing me an error - TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function

Comment: are you using it like `$("#name").tabs();` and not `$("#name").tabs;`

Comment: I was using $("#name").tabs();.. but somehow issue was totally different. It is resolved..Thanks.!

Answer (score 0):

I had included jquery.js in one of the included jsp page which was causing the issue & the browser was not able to load the jquery files.